# how to remove the argument not optional error

Tags: excel, vba

i want to call the function vector in the sub.but when i run it it gives error argument not optional and highlights vector.what should i do

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1

Sub JumbleArray()
Dim n As Integer, rng As Range, Z As Variant, rn As Integer, tem As Integer, j As Integer
Dim k As Integer
Set rng = Range("A1:C3")
**Z = myfunction(vector)**
For j = 1 To n
    rn = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, n - j + 1)
    tem = Z(n - j + 1)
    Z(n - j + 1) = Z(rn)
    Z(rn) = tem
Next j
End Sub
Function vector(rng As Range)
Dim nr As Integer, nc As Integer, i As Integer, j As Integer, temp()
nr = rng.Rows.Count
nc = rng.Columns.Count
ReDim temp(nr * nc)
For i = 1 To nr
    For j = 0 To nc - 1
    temp((j * nr) + i) = rng.Cells(i, j + 1)
    Next j
Next i
temp = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(temp)
vector = temp
End Function
```

Comment: Just replace `Z = myfunction(vector)` with `Z = Vector(rng)`.

Answer (score 0):

That's not how you call a function. You probably mean this:

```
Set rng = Range("A1:C3")

Z = vector(rng)
```

Comment: after the above is done how do i count the number of rows in the function output

Comment: Your question was about how to remove the not optional error. If you have an additional question, please close this question using the green checkmark on the left, and then create a new question that addresses your new issue.